# R . How to subsetting a row which have () parentheses in the name?

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, dplyr, parentheses

I am very noob to R, and I am trying a plot.

The file contain a bunch of rows with 4 different names, I can subsetting someones, but I have problems with others which have parenthesis in the text. How I can subsetting theses?

I am trying to reorder too, but i can`t

Thank you much in advance!

The file is this : [link to .csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vDf6nkklgESgFexaHPhR0LXYcTw1_wca/view?usp=sharing)

```
library(tidyverse)

dfagro<- read.csv("C:/Users/../data.csv", encoding = "ASCII", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
colnames(dfagro) <- c("time","GEO", "crop", "stuc", "Value", "flag")

# dfagro$Value = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",dfagro$Value))

# dfagro %>%
# mutate(GEO = fct_reorder(GEO, Value)) %>%

ggplot(subset(dfagro, crop %in% c("Permanent crops for human consumption")), aes(x=GEO, y=Value)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.6) + coord_flip()      # +
  #geom_text(data=dfagro, aes(y=Value,label=Value),vjust=1)
```

the problem came when I try to plot this kind of rows with ():

```
# ggplot(subset(dfagro, crop %in% c("Fresh vegetables (including melons)")), aes(x = GEO, y = Value))+
```

Comment: the link is not working

Comment: `ggplot(subset(dfagro, crop == "Fresh vegetables (including melons)"), aes(x=GEO, y=Value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.6) + coord_flip()   
` works absolutely fine for me on your data. Can you check?

Comment: Yeah! works fine! thank you so much. But, how to mutate, for reorder to major to minor ? I have tried with your lines and mutate and give me warnings but don´t print the chart..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
dfagro %>%
        mutate(GEO = fct_reorder(GEO, Value)) %>%
        filter(crop %in% "Permanent crops for human consumption")
```

Comment: I have tried this, but don´t work :                                 library(tidyverse)

library(dplyr)



dfagro<- read.csv("C:/Users/BlackMamba/Desktop/xy/AGRO/data.csv", encoding = "ASCII", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
colnames(dfagro) <- c("time","GEO", "crop", "stuc", "Value", "flag")
 
                                                                 
dfagro %>%
  mutate(GEO = fct_reorder(GEO, Value)) %>%
  filter(crop %in% "Permanent crops for human consumption")

Comment: @Raul Please show a small reproducible example as your link is not working

Comment: I have uploaded right now to google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vDf6nkklgESgFexaHPhR0LXYcTw1_wca/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I just tried filtering your data with dplyr and had no problem at all. If you want to filter just one value, you don't need the infix `%in%`, just use the operator `==` .

Comment: really? I have tried with %in% and with == and I can´t able to plot the chart.  Only give me this message: There were 41 warnings (use warnings() to see them)  without the mutate part I am able to plot the data. Something its something